# How to make an array flexible?

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays, sql-server-2008

```
  public List<int> GetCounts(string connectionstring)
    {
        List<int> results = new List<int>();
        string sqlStmt = "SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(Grouping) from Attendance";

        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=localhost\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=PSeminar;Integrated Security=true;Trusted_Connection=Yes;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"))
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(conn,sqlStmt))
        {
            conn.Open();
            using (SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (rdr.Read())
                {
                    int count = rdr.GetInt32(0);

                    results.Add(count);
                }
                rdr.Close();
            }
            conn.Close();
        }
        return results;
    }
```

Currently I have this code, I want the array to be flexible, meaning if i have more than two items in the database the array will be automatically updated. The above sql statement will retrieve the items that i want to put in the array above. If the sql statement result has more than 2 items i want the array to be updated automatically.

Comment: Use a `List<string>` instead.... arrays are of a given, fixed length at any point in time...

Comment: @marc_s updated the question,can you please give me some codes for me to follow?

Comment: recommendation stays the same - use a `List<string>` instead which is flexible in the number of entries you can put in it.

Comment: It looks like the question was updated to match the correct answer. This makes it very hard for visitors to understand the original question. Can you please edit the code example to match the question?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to retrieve an arbitrary number of items from the database, I would suggest the `List<T>` construct over an array.

Try this:

```
public List<int> GetCounts(string connectionString)
{
   List<int> results = new List<int>();

   string sqlStmt = "SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(Grouping) from Attendance";

   using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
   using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlStmt, conn))
   {
      conn.Open();

      using(SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
      {
          while(rdr.Read())
          {
              int count = rdr.GetInt32(0);  // read item no. 0 from the reader, as INT

              results.Add(count);
          }  

          rdr.Close();
      }

      conn.Close();
   }

   return results;
}
```

and then you could call this method like this:

```
string connStr = @"Data Source=localhost\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=PSeminar;Integrated Security=true;Trusted_Connection=Yes;";

List<int> counts = GetCounts(connStr);
```

and you get back a list of all your counts - as many as there are - no dirty array hacks or anything necessary!

The `List<T>` construct is very flexible, too - you can have a `List<string>` or a list of any .NET type, really - you can build your own types (e.g. a class consisting of ten properties) and then have a list of that class type. Generics are cool! :-)

Comment: thanks! I have editted the codes, now I have error at   using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(conn, sqlStmt)) saying it has some invalid arguments, and that it cannot convert from string to System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection =/

Comment: @Mark20: Oh, sorry - I mixed up the two parameters - the `SqlStmt` (string) must come first, the `conn` (SqlConnection) last

Answer (score 0):

Use `FieldCount` property of `SqlDataReader` to create an array. You can also use `SqlDataReader.GetValues(object[])` method to populate an array of objects with column values in current row.

Hope it helps you.